# Composition operator on Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to consider hypothesis on $g$ such that the operator
$$ H_0^1 (\Omega) \to H^{-1}(\Omega), \qquad v \mapsto g(v) $$
is $\mathcal C^1$. Of course, $g(0) = 0$.

I believe that $g \in W^{2,\infty} (\mathbb R)$ is sufficient, but I am quite stuck on the proof.

Thanks in advance,

D

**Edit:** It is, of course, enough that it be differentiable $H^1 (\Omega) \to L^2 (\Omega)$.

Comment: Did you mean $g\in W^{2,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$? Is this a composition operator?

Comment: Of course, just edited. Wouldn't make sense any other way. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is bounded, then for $w\in H^1(\Omega)$,
$$
|\langle g(v),w\rangle| \le  \int_\Omega |g(v)|\cdot|w| dx \le M \|w\|_{L^1(\Omega)},
$$
and you are done. As you can see, there is a lot of room to relax the assumptions on $g$. In fact, one can allow a certain growth of $g(x)$ for $|x|\to\infty$.
Then $g$ is well-defined.

Since $g \in W^{2,\infty}$ it is of class $C^1$. Thus for $x,y\in\mathbb R$,
$$
g(y)-g(x)-g'(x)(x-y)=\frac12 g''(\xi)\cdot|x-y|^2
$$ 
with $\xi$ between $x,y$. Since $g''$ is essentially bounded, we obtain
$$
|g(y)-g(x)-g'(x)(x-y)|\le M|x-y|^2\quad \forall x,y\in\mathbb R.
$$
Now take $v,w,u\in H^1(\Omega)$, then
$$
\int_\Omega |(g(v)-g(u)-g'(u)(v-u))w|dx  \le
M \int_\Omega |v-u|^2 w \le M \|v-u\|_{L^3(\Omega)} \|w\|_{L^3(\Omega)}.
$$
Since $H^1(\Omega)$ is continuously embedded into $L^3(\Omega)$ for spatial dimension $\le 6$, we found that the Frechet derivative $g'$ of $g$ at $v$ is given by
$$
\langle g'(v)z,w\rangle = \int_\Omega g'(v)zw \ dx.
$$
Again, there is some room for improvement: if spatial dimension is strictly less than $6$, you can even allow for a certain growth rate of $g''(x)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Continuity of $v\mapsto g'(v)$ can be proven similarly, by using
$$
|g'(y)-g'(x)| = |g''(\xi)(y-x)| \le M |y-x|,
$$
the growth requirements for $g''$ are the same as in the proof of Frechet differentiability.

Comment: That is correct. You have shown that the functional is well defined. However, I was asking about $C^1$, that is about it been, at least, continuous with continuous frechet derivative. Your argument would translate into continuity as
$$   <g(v)  - g(w) , z > \le C \| g(v) - g(w) \|_1 \| z \| _2$$
Now, when does $v_n \to v$ in $H^1 (\Omega)$ imply that $g(v_n) \to g(v)$ in $L^\infty$. This, of course, is not very general. So, does any know about continuous differentiability results?

Comment: will expand the answer...

Comment: Thank you. How about other dimensions. Do you know any reference I might look up?

Comment: I am pretty confident that the function $g$ is not Frechet differentiable for $N>6$. As I have shown it is Frechet from $L^3(\Omega)$ to $(L^3(\Omega)^*$, and by embedding the result follows. In higher dimensions, you have to work with the space $H^1(\Omega)\cap L^3(\Omega)$.

To construct a counterexample, you have to take functions from $H^1(\Omega)$ that are not in $L^3(\Omega)$, $n>7$.

Comment: A reference would be for instance: Appell/Zabrejko - Nonlinear superposition operators.

Comment: Why are you interested in large-dimensional spaces?

Comment: I am a mathematician and intend to show the result in the most general setting possible

Comment: @daw why did you put a $w$ in your 4th displayed equation? To show it's frechet, I choose $v=u+h$ and see no reason for the presence of $w$

Comment: The question was about differentiability of $g$ with values in a dual space, so $w$ is a test function to estimate the norm of the remainder in the dual space.